# favicon automatically download in browser

Tags: favicon

i am using favicon this code.

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

But favicon is automatically downloading in browser.

Please help us how can we resolve this issue..

Comment: What is the problem? When you declare favicon.ico, it is downloaded when the page is loaded, I see nothing wrong here. Please edit your question and rephrase it.

Comment: Favicon is downloading when page load. I am unable to judge issue, please help...

Comment: What do you mean by "downloading"? The browser opens a popup and ask you where to save favicon.ico?

Comment: yes favicon asking, where to save favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

My advice:

- In the HTML declaration, use an absolute path (ie. `/images/favicon.ico`), to avoid any relative path issue.
- Download the file manually (eg. download `http://yourwebsite.com/images/favicon.ico`) and open it with an image editor. This is to make sure that your web server really returns your `favicon.ico` file and not something else. When a file does not exist, some web servers are configured to return some content, such as a "Oops!" web page, instead of a plain 404 error. This can trick the browser.
- When opening your page, enable your favorite web debuging tool (Firefox+Firebug, Chrome console...), select the Network tab to look at the HTTP exchanges and spot the access to `favicon.ico`. Check the Mime type: it should be `image/x-icon` (or maybe something similar). If you see something really suspicious, such as `application/octet-stream`, there must be something wrong on the server side.